# Using LINQ to compare on a string value

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a string value in which I need to do a compare on in an IF statement. However, I need to check the compare in a List object that contains a type string, how do I go about this in one line if possible (or using LINQ)?

For example I was going down the lines off

```
If "example" = m_listObject.ForEach(Function(x) x.stringValue)) Then
...
```

Of course this won't work but I hope you know what I mean,

Yes, I could do it in a `for each` or a `for` but I want to use LINQ if possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Any()`:

```
If m_listObject.Any(Function(f) f.stringValue = "example") Then
    'some more code
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Any`:-

```
If(m_listObject.Any(Function(x) x.stringValue = "example")) Then
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Find :

```
If m_listObject.Find(Function(x) x.stringValue.equals("example", StringComaprison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).count > 0 Then
    ...
End If
```